# How can I remove thousands of spam members on a non-member site?

Tags: members, database, spam

My first EE 1.6.8 site is coming back to haunt me. The site crashed and burned the other day. Took a look at the members in the DB and there's about 78000 spam members in there. I have access to PHPAdmin for the DB, but I don't know what I'm doing in there. Any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Always backup first!**

Hopefully they're all still pending. Go into phpMyAdmin query tab and run the following query to delete pending members:

```
DELETE FROM exp_members WHERE group_id = 'PENDING GROUP ID'
```

You can also run the query right from the control panel:

> Admin › Utilities › SQL Manager › Database Query Form

If the site isn't setup to verify membership, you could run a query to delete all members after a certain date, specifically the day of spam and after:

```
DELETE FROM exp_members WHERE join_date > 'UNIXTIMESTAMP'
```

Use this tool to help figure out the [unix timestamp](http://www.unixtimestamp.com/). If you don't feel comfortable running the query at first, you could always run a `SELECT` query to confirm correct selection of members.

```
SELECT * FROM exp_members WHERE join_date > 'UNIXTIMESTAMP'
```

Comment: Thanks Siebird! I ran the query on exp_members for group_id that all the spam registrations had. I also ran queries for a couple other things and it was a success. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, I didn't have any previous experience running db queries.

Comment: Awesome, glad you got it sorted!